# Form values not passed by jquery submission

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a form embedded in table that is created on the initial page load:

```
echo "<form id='showbooking' action='calendar.php' method='post'>";
echo "<td name='clickedcalid' value='" . $resarr[$k]['calid'];
echo "' title='" . $resarr[$k]['coms'] . "' class='hols'>";
echo $resarr[$k]['typ'] . "</td></form>";
```

I submit the form when a cell in the table is clicked and want to pass the value of the cell that was clicked.

```
<script>
$(".hols").click(function() {
    $("#showbooking").submit();
})
</script>
```

After the reload I am testing with this:

```
echo "<p> ID of clicked booking was: " . $_POST['clickedcalid']; . "</p>";
```

but the value is not being passed and I'm not sure why.

Possibly because the form is embedded in a table?

Comment: A form tag wrappring a td `Oo`

Comment: There should be input element named as `clickedcalid` tds will not pass data

Comment: use form-elements like <input type="text" value="xyz> to make use of a  submit()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put `<form>` inside a `tr` element, wrapping `td`. `<tr>` [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr) says

> Permitted content: Zero or more <td> or <th> elements, or a mix of them

Also `value` attribute is not valid for `td` element. You need to restructure your markup.

```
echo '<td class="hols" title="' . $resarr[$k]['coms'] . '">' .
    '<form id="showbooking" action="calendar.php" method="post">' .
        '<input type="hidden" name="clickedcalid" value="' . $resarr[$k]['calid'] . '">' .
        $resarr[$k]['typ'] .
    '</form>' .
'</td>';
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the `form` element needs to go inside the `td`. Secondly, only the values of form elements are sent in a form submission, ie `input`, `select`, `textarea` etc. Try this:

```
echo '<td class="hols" title="' . $resarr[$k]['coms'] . '">';
echo '<form id="showbooking" action="calendar.php" method="post">';
echo '<input type="text" name="clickedcalid" value="' . $resarr[$k]['calid'] . '" />';
echo $resarr[$k]['typ'] . '</form></td>';
```

Comment: Great, this works. I'm getting the impression this seems like pretty bad practice though, would you suggest coming at it from a different angle?

Comment: Why did you use `text` input? In OP's code, it's the `value` attribute of `td` which is not supposed to be rendered on the page.

Comment: I did change the input type to hidden to make it work

Comment: @AlistairWeir, so why didn't you use my answer in the first place?

Comment: I thought your revision to include code was made after this was posted but looks like it wasn't. Both are good answers.

Answer (score -1):

To get value from $_POST you need to have input tag

```
echo "<form id='showbooking' action='calendar.php' method='post'>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='clickedcalid' value='" . $resarr[$k]['calid'];
echo "' title='" . $resarr[$k]['coms'] . "' class='hols' />";
echo $resarr[$k]['typ'] . "</td></form>";
```

Thanks,
Naumche

Comment: `<form>` must be a child of `<td>`.